# Laravel One-to-One relationship not working

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have 2 database tables => `mobile_phones` , `mobile_users`

Schema for `mobile_phones`

- phone_id  (primary key , auto_increment)
- phone_name (varchar(150))
- phone_model (int (11))

Schema for `mobile_users`

- user_id  (primary key , auto_increment)
- username (varchar(150))
- mobile_phone_id (foreign key referencing mobile_phones(phone_id))

Model class for `mobile_phones`

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class MobilePhone extends Model
{
    protected $primaryKey = "phone_id";
    public $timestamps = false;
    protected $table = "mobile_phones";
    protected $fillable = array("phone_name","phone_model");

    public function mobileUser()
    {
        return $this->hasOne("MobileUser","mobile_phone_id");
    }

}
```

Model class for `mobile_users`

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class MobileUser extends Model
{
    protected $primaryKey = "user_id";
    public $timestamps = false;
    protected $table = "mobile_users";
    protected $fillable = array("username","mobile_phone_id");

    public function mobilePhone()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo("MobilePhone","phone_id");
    }


}
```

I am trying to establish One-to-One relationship between `MobileUser` and `MobilePhone` models but it isn't happening. Below is my code in Controller's action -

```
public function query()
    {
       $getUsername = MobilePhone::find(1)->username;        
       echo $getUsername;
    }
```

The above code gives me `NULL` when I do a `var_dump()` 
I did check similar questions on SO and they used `with()` (but this isn't necessary). I am referring Laravel 5.2 docs and they state that we can access relate record in another relation using Eloquent's dynamic properties. Link to that docs is [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships#defining-relationships)

Please Help !!

Comment: It looks like mobile_users has a foreign key to Mobile_phones, but not the other way around. So if you want to access the username, you'd have to use the MobileUser class, not the MobilePhone class.

Comment: If I don't use  `MobilePhone `  class and directly use `MobileUser`  class , then there was no need to define relationship between the 2 models . According to the docs ,  `MobilePhone::find(1)->username`  will  internally perform the Primary key - Foreign Key  mapping  and get the username who has  a  mobile phone of id 1 .

Comment: you want mobile phone of respective user or vise-versa  ??

Comment: I want  to `retrieve` the username who has mobile phone of id `1` .

Answer (score 0):

Something like this :

```
public function query()
    {
       $getUsername = MobilePhone::find(1)->mobileUser;        
       echo $getUsername->username;
    }
```

Comment: Nope. Not working . `mobileusers`  isn't related to anything. Did you mean `mobileUser` ?

Comment: Yeah, it should be `mobileUser', typo mistake.

Answer (score 0):

When doing this:

```
public function query()
    {
       $getUsername = MobilePhone::find(1)->username;        
       echo $getUsername;
    }
```

You try to access a `username` property out of a `MobilePhone` number, which is incorrect.

Try this:

```
public function query()
    {
       $getUsername = MobilePhone::find(1)->mobileUser->username;        
       echo $getUsername;
    }
```

Also I encourage you to use the `with` statement as it will preload all dependencies needed (means 1 single query) instead of eager loading it (many queries)

Comment: Tried. It says `Call to undefined method MobileUser::newQuery()`

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the function of your model so do the following

```
public function query()
{
       $getUsername = MobilePhone::find(1)->mobileusers;        
       echo $getUsername->username;
}
```

Comment: It says `Trying to get property of non-object` followed  by a huge error stack trace.

Comment: why would he call `->mobileusers` if the model property is `mobileUser` (1 to 1 rel)